# EReferenceError: AWSCognito is not defined - Error in AWS Cognito

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have used AWS Cognito for the sign up function. I have referred the below link

https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/blob/master/README.md

I  have included these files

```
var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
var CognitoUserPool = AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool;
```

And when I use this below code, it gives the above error

```
var attributeEmail = new 
AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataEmail);
```

This is the users.js file which includes the above codes

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
   var CognitoUserPool = AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool;


   var firstName = req.query.name;
   var lastName = req.query.familyName;
   var email = req.query.email;
   var phoneNumber = req.query.phoneNumber;
   var address = req.query.address;

  var poolData = {
    UserPoolId : '-----', // Your user pool id here
    ClientId : '----' // Your client id here
   };
  var userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);

  var attributeList = [];

  var dataEmail = {
    Name : 'email',
    Value : email
  };
  var dataPhoneNumber = {
    Name : 'phone_number',
    Value : phoneNumber
  };
  var dataName = {
    Name : 'name',
    Value : firstName
  };
  var dataFamilyName = {
    Name : 'family_name',
    Value : lastName
  };
  var dataAddress = {
    Name : 'address',
    Value : address
 };


  var username = firstName.concat(lastName);
  var password = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);


  var attributeEmail = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataEmail);
  var attributePhoneNumber = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataPhoneNumber;
  var attributeName = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataName);
 var attributeFamilyName = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataFamilyName);
 var attributeAddress = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute(dataAddress);


  attributeList.push(attributeEmail);
  attributeList.push(attributePhoneNumber);
  attributeList.push(attributeName);
  attributeList.push(attributeFamilyName);
  attributeList.push(attributeAddress);

  userPool.signUp(username, password, attributeList, null, function(err, result){
    if (err) {
        alert(err);
        return;
    }
    cognitoUser = result.user;
    console.log('user name is ' + cognitoUser.getUsername());
  });


  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Its really great if someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found a solution. When I remove the "CognitoIdentityServiceProvider" part, it works

Comment: I'm sure others would find a benefit if you posted this in the answer section followed perhaps by why removing `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider` works.